# Categorical variables with only two values

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, labeling

I am dealing with different datasets that have only Categorical variables/features with **only two values** such as (**temperature = 'low' and 'high'**) or (**light = 'on' and 'off'** or '0' and '1').

I am not really sure whether to use **"one-hot encoding"** or **"Label Encoding"** method to train my models. 
I am working on a classification problem and using some supervised machine learning algorithms.

I used **"Label Encoding"** and I got a pretty good result. I feel there could be something that I did was wrong. I am not sure if I should use **"one-hot encoding"** or not.

In case of Categorical variables **with only two values** which method should I use to convert the variables?

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few cases where LabelEncoder is useful because of the ordinality issue. If your categorial features are ordinal then use LabelEncoder otherwise use One-hot encoding. But, One-hot encoding increases dimension. In this case, I typically employ One-hot encoding followed by PCA for dimensionality reduction.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I kind of understand that but in case of binary data which method is preferable. I saw the different data type in this link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159902/is-nominal-ordinal-binary-for-quantitative-data-qualitative-data-or-both.

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer. **Which encoding techniques can be used for binary features ?**. I know that LabelEncoder is better for an ordinal data and One-hot encoding is better for a nominal data. Yet, I am not sure in a case of binary data which one is recommended.

Comment: I am new to ML, based on my understanding One-hot encoding is best in that case. Since the data is binary.